# How to run Apk inside android app

Tags: apk

I'm having an issue.
Can I make an android project and call an apk file inside this project and run it?
Thanks you and hope for receiving all your help.

Comment: Post your current work.

Comment: I have an exist apk file. Now I want create a blank android project with the same package name with the above apk file. Can I call and run the apk file inside my new project?